# Weird android fragment issue using back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have following issue with Android compatibility package fragments.
There is following hierarchy of fragments:

A(login) -> B(dashboard) -> C(details)

Login fragment is added with function:

```
private void addFragment(Fragment f) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_content, f);
    ft.commit();
}
```

After successfull login dashboard is added same way, without adding transaction to backstack. C fragment is added like:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_content, f, id);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

So basically on detail screen I have logout button, which should bring me to login A and remove all fragments from backstack. According to android developer docs:

> Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is stopped and will be resumed if the user navigates back.

But it is not the issue in my case. When logout is pressed in C fragment:

```
getFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_content, new LoginFragment());
ft.commit();
```

onActivityCreated(), onStart() of B fragment are also called (instead of onResume written in docs), making my code crash because in this fragment Im starting some thread operation, and after adding login fragment I got IllegalStateException that fragment B is not attached to an activity (when thread operation is over it updates fragment UI) Do anyone knows how replace really works and how overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should call 
addToBackStack for each fragment you add giving a different name to them.
Reading your code seems to me you don't do it.

Comment: as I mentioned, issue concern fragment C, which I add with call to addToBackStack(null).